# How can I check if 2d array is unique only with for loops

Tags: c#

how would I go about checking a duplicate for columns and rows and return true or false depending if there's duplicates. For example

1 2 3

3 1 2

2 3 1

Would return true because no duplicates, but..

1 2 2

3 2 3

2 1 1

would return false because there is a duplicate in column 2 {2, 2, 1}.

How would I go about checking for if there are in duplicates in the rows and then checking if there are duplicates in the columns?

Also I need to check every single number to compere with the others numbers on the same row and same colum

So far I have only the following:

```
 for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < m; col++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Check for: " + arr[row, col]);
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", arr[row, col], arr[i, col]);
                    if (col != i)
                    {
                        if (arr[row, col] == arr[i, col])
                        {
                            unique = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                for (int j = 1; j < arr.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", arr[row, col], arr[row, j]);
                    if (row != j)
                    {
                        if (arr[row, col] == arr[row, j])
                        {
                            unique = false;
                        }
                    }



                }
```

I am stuck on that assigment since 2 days and i dont know how to make the right check with the last two for loops. 
Also I am supposed to use only for loops and only 2d array not jagged nor HashSets .

Thank you in advance.

Hey guys so to all of you to be able to chek every single number from every singel row and colum to get unique matrix in 2d when using only for loops your for loops for the rows and colums should start from 0 and loop depends for the rows the width and the colums for the hight then the most important thing is in the if statment so when the loop beggins and check if the index which cheks the colums and the one for the rows is  the same as the number it cheks it has  to continue then you go to the second if statment which is if the index for the row or column isnt the same as the row or column of which is it right now and the array of row and col == array of index, col or array of row, index then the matrix is not unique. I will post the code as well so you could see the final result. Thanks to all of you guys who hellped me guided me to the right direction

```
for (int row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < arr.GetLength(1); col++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Check for: " + arr[row, col]);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    if (i == row)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", arr[row, col], arr[i, col]);
                    if (i != row && arr[row, col] == arr[i, col])
                    {
                        unique = false;
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (j == col)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", arr[row, col], arr[row, j]);
                    if (j != col && arr[row, col] == arr[row, j])
                    {
                        unique = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: If there are 3 columns, are the numbers in those three columns **always** 1, 2 and 3? Or could they be other numbers (e.g. 1, 2 and 4)? The reason I ask is that if they can _only_ be 1, 2 and 3 the problem is considerably simpler.

Comment: it can be even 123,456,789   since this is a unique matrix

Comment: So, as an example, if the first row of the array contained 4 and 89 and 123 that would be valid?

Comment: It has to be unique no matter the numbers I have used 123,231,312 just as an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check duplicate values horizontally and vertically in a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871105/how-to-check-duplicate-values-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): working code, including the array you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[,] arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 1, 2 }, { 2, 3, 1 } };
// int[,] arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 2 }, { 3, 2, 3 }, { 2, 1, 1 } };
int r = arr.GetLength(0), c = arr.GetLength(1);
bool unique = true;

for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
    {
        for (int i = row + 1; i < r; i++)
            if (arr[row, col] == arr[i, col])
            {
                unique = false;
                break;
            }

        for (int j = col + 1; j < r; j++)
            if (arr[row, col] == arr[row, j])
            {
                unique = false;
                break;
            }
    }
Console.WriteLine(unique);
```

If your array always is square(Col == Row), you can use this. One loop is less.

```
// int[,] arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 1, 2 }, { 2, 3, 1 } };
int[,] arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 2 }, { 3, 2, 3 }, { 2, 1, 1 } };

int len = arr.GetLength(0);
bool unique = true;

for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < len; r++)
        if (r != x && arr[x, x] == arr[r, x])
        {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }

    for (int c = x + 1; c < len; c++)
        if (c != x && arr[x, x] == arr[x, c])
        {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
}
Console.WriteLine(unique);
```

Comment: So actualy I am using input form the console so I tryed your answer and it didint work I will post my entier code so you can see

Comment: the problem is that i can't post it here . Can I send you DM

Comment: Can we send social media id here? For example WhatsApp id or Telegram id or etc. Maybe Github or Gitlab are better choices.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a helper Method which checks a Sequence for duplicates. You could use the same Algorithm for Rows and for Colums.

```
        public bool SequenceHasDuplicateSymbols(char[] sequence) {

            char symbolToCheckFor;         
            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
            {
                symbolToCheckFor = sequence[i];

                for (int j = 0; j < sequence.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j)
                    {
                        if (symbolToCheckFor == sequence[j])
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to check your rows and columns for duplicates, kind of like a sudoku.

I'd suggest that you create a helper method which checks duplicate in arrays, and then run this method once with every row and column.

```
private bool checkForDuplicateInArray(int[] arr)
    {
        var result = false;
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            foreach (int j in arr)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }
```

Now you just split your 2D array in rows and columns and run the method with it.

```
        var result = true;

        // rows
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2d.Length; i++)
        {
            int[] arrToCheck = new int[arr2d[i].Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2d[i].Length; j++)
            {
                arrToCheck[j] = arr2d[i][j];
            }
            if(!checkForDuplicateInArray(arrToCheck))
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }

        // columns
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2d[0].Length; i++)
        {
            int[] arrToCheck = new int[arr2d.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2d.Length; j++)
            {
                arrToCheck[j] = arr2d[j][i];
            }
            if (!checkForDuplicateInArray(arrToCheck))
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
```

Edit: Assumed overall true means there is no duplicate